# How to create a user in mySql, including password

Tags: mysql, createuser

I created a new user by inserting into the user table in mySql database - but it showed up an error saying there is no such column titled "password". Which column is responsible for password in user table in mySql database?

```
mysql> INSERT INTO user 
          (host, user, password, 
           select_priv, insert_priv, update_priv) 
           VALUES ('localhost', 'guest', 
           PASSWORD('guest123'), 'Y', 'Y', 'Y');
```

Comment: google is your friend. first result for "mysql create new user" https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html

Comment: Why don't you use the `CREATE USER` statement instead?

Answer (score 6):

This is the way to create new user in MySQL

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

And this is the way you give the user permission:

It seems like the permission of user "parser" is not correct. You can check the configuration of user with statement.

```
SELECT * FROM  information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGES;
```

If you have granted a user new permission, you have to reload the settings. You can do this with this `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

How To Grant Different User Permissions:

- ALL PRIVILEGES- as we saw previously, this would allow a MySQL user
  all access to a designated database (or if no database is selected,
  across the system)
- CREATE- allows them to create new tables or
  databases
- DROP- allows them to them to delete tables or databases
- DELETE- allows them to delete rows from tables INSERT- allows them to
  insert rows into tables
- SELECT- allows them to use the Select command
  to read through databases
- UPDATE- allow them to update table rows
- GRANT OPTION- allows them to grant or remove other users' privileges

To provide a specific user with a permission, you can use this framework:

```
GRANT [type of permission] ON [database name].[table name] TO ‘[username]’@'localhost’;
```

I hope this will help you solve your issue. Never forget to flush!!!